# Criar uma galeria de imagens

Tags: html, css, html5

Estou iniciando um projeto e gostaria de criar uma página com uma galeria como no esquema abaixo:

[image: Como eu quero]
Site que possui a [Galeria](https://megascans.se/gallery)

Pelo que parece as imagens são disponibilizadas por linhas, só que consegui fazer apenas disponibilizando as imagens por colunas seguindo [este exemplo](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_image_grid), mas não ficou muito legal.

Como eu poderia fazer uma galeria igual a esta do exemplo? Alguém pode me indicar um caminho ou exemplos?

Obs.: Só quero conseguir disponibilizar as imagens como no exemplo acima e pretendo carregar as imagens utilizando AngularJS.

**Editado**

Esse é a minha página HTML atualmente

```css
   /*CSS Photos*/
#photoContainer {
  width: 1200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: black;
  /*transparent*/
  position: absolute;
  /*top: 350px;*/
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}


/*photobanner*/

.photobanner {
  /*height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 display: inline;*/
}

.photobanner img {
  /*max-width:350px;
    max-height:233px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
 margin: 20px;*/
  /*Animação zoom*/
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.photobanner img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -o-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 4px;
}


/* Create two equal columns that sits next to each other */

.column {
  flex: 25%;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.column img {
  margin-top: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}


/* Responsive layout - makes a two column-layout instead of four columns */

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .column {
    flex: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
}


/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    flex: 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="controllerPrincipal">

<head>
  <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.png" />
  <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--Import materialize.css-->
  <!--<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.css"  media="screen,projection"/>-->
  <link href="css/CardStyle.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection" />
  <link href="css/mainstyle.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection" />
  <link href="css/photos.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>
      <nav>
        <div class="menu-icon"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></div>
        <div class="logo">LOGO</div>
        <div class="menu">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="container" ng-controller="PesquisaFotos">
        <div id="photoContainer">
          <div class="row photobanner" ng-repeat="item in dados">
            <div class="column">
              <img class="img first" src="{{ item.foto }}" alt="{{ item.descricao }}" style="width:100%" />
            </div>
            <div class="column">
              <img class="img first" src="{{ item.foto }}" alt="{{ item.descricao }}" style="width:100%" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
        survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
        publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
        survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
        publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Scripts-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: Como está]

Está meio bagunçado pois estou fazendo testes

Comment: Coloque o código que já tens, que o pessoal ajuda. O padrão que eu percebo é que as fotos tem a mesma altura, só muda a largura. Acredito que definindo uma altura padrão e usando uma função para corta a imagem(não lembro se é `overflow:clip`, alguma coisa assim). MAs bota o código ae...

Comment: @MagicHat Adicionei o meu fonte atual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara com `display:flex` e `object-fit:cover` vc consegue só com CSS eum resultado muito próximo disso e ainda deixa tudo com uma boa responsividade inclusive.

Veja no exemplo:

**EDIT OBS1:** deixei comentado no css como controlar a largura máxima das imgs, só que agora vai abrir alguns buracos na galeria, pois a imagem fica com um largura máxima e não a largura total da tela.

**OBS2:** Exiba em "*Página toda*" para ver melhor o resultado

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #000;
}
.grid {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.grid .wrapper {
    height: 100px;
    max-width: 300px; /* largura máxima dos boxes*/
    overflow: hidden;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
.grid .wrapper img {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0.4em 0.4em;
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/1000/1000" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/100/300" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/100" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/300" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/440" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/100" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/100/400" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/240" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://placecage.com/400/440" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/500/400" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/300" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/100/400" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/440" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/100" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/500/300" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/300" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/100/440" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/200" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://placecage.com/100/400" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/500/200" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/400" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/440" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/500" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/100" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/100/300" alt="">
    </div>

</div>
```

**Dica:** vc pode testar tirando `object-fit` e o `widhr:100%` para ver se te agrada tb, mas ai as imgs não vai ficar coladinhas uma na outra na horizontal

Comment: Funcionou legal a sua resposta, só que preciso por imagens já pequenas certo? Como no seu exemplo você usou imagens com dimensões de 300/300, 100/400. Aqui eu coloquei algumas imagens de 1920x1281 ai ficou a linha toda uma unica imagem

Comment: @MatheusRibeiro já corrigi isso, bastou acrescentar um `max-width: 300px;` agora mesmo a imagem tenho 1000px de lagura ela vai ficar com no máximo 300px, deixei comentado no CSS como controlar essa largura. Repare que deixei a primeira imagem da galeria com 1000px de largura e altura e não ocupou a linha inteira.

Comment: @MatheusRibeiro só que agora ela cria alguns "buracos" pois ela não ajusta 100% da largura como antes... as vezes com um JS vc consegue corrigir isso, mas nessa não consigo te ajudar pq não manjo nada de JS... Mas lembre-se que uma galeria com imagens de mais de 1000px vai demorar uma eternidade para carregar, isso não vai ser legal pro usuário...

Comment: É o que eu pensei mesmo então, na questão da imagem era só uma curiosidade mesmo  kkkkkkkk Sei que demora pra carregar, não irei deixar tão grande assim, muito obrigado

Comment: @MatheusRibeiro eu não cheguei a testar, mas vc pode colocar um width fix apenas em uma imegem ou outra se precisar... vc pode fazer um teste e ver como a galeria vai se comportar dessa forma. Cria uma classe com um width máximo e usa só nas imagens que forem grandes de mais, nas outras vc deixa auto. Boa sorte ai tmj!

Answer (score -1):

Veja se isso te da uma luz.

```css
.portifolio {
  width: 1100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.portifolio img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="portifolio">
      <div id="img1">
        <img src="#">
      </div>
      <div id="img2">
        <img src="#">
      </div>
</div>
```

No css você pode controlar as coluna. Assim você defini um tamanho, como width, assim a imagem redimensiona proporcionalmente e da esse feito ai que você usou como exemplo.

Comment: Esqueci de por meu código... Mas é quase isso que estou fazendo já, mas assim que der eu testo o que falou

Comment: Se você colocar essa logica no seu CSS vai funciona, mas não esqueça de redimensionar suas fotos, pois depende muito do tamanho delas pra dar esse efeito que você quer. Determinando todas as imagens com a mesma altura e numero de 3 colunas. Assim as larguras vão se basear proporcionalmente. Mas o conceito e esse, usei um igual em portfólio que fiz para um cliente.

Comment: A sua resposta funcionou bem também e deu pra comparar bem, mas vi que por colunas não fica muito legal pro que quero, deu uma esclarecida nas ideias. A resposta do @hugocsl foi mais diretamente o que eu preciso, mas mesmo assim obrigado pela ajuda!